# Spark Cassandra Integration using Calliope Library- Not displaying any records

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

Trying connect Cassandra using tuplejump Calliope-sql via spark-shell.

Spark version 1.1.0:

**Connection:**

```
./spark-shell  --master spark://PCSS-HDOP04:7077 --jars calliope-sql-assembly-1.1.0-CTP-U2.jar,calliope-sql_2.10-1.1.0-CTP-U2.jar,spark-cassandra-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar,stargate-core-0.9.9.jar,calliope-core-assembly-1.1.0-CTP-U2.jar --conf "spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.234.31.231"
```

**Commands Executed:**

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
 val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.234.31.231")
 val sc = new SparkContext("spark://PCSS-HDOP04:7077", "test", conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.CassandraAwareSQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
sqlContext.sql("select * from roadtrips.roadtrip")
```

**Output:**

```
scala> val res = sqlContext.sql("select * from roadtrips.roadtrip")
15/01/15 14:55:41 INFO CassandraAwareSQLContext$$anon$1: LOOKING UP DB [None] for CF [roadtrips.roadtrip]
15/01/15 14:55:41 INFO CassandraAwareSQLContext$$anon$1: INTERPRETED AS DB [Some(roadtrips)] for CF [roadtrip]
ArrayBuffer(id#21, destination_city_name#22, destination_state_abr#23, distance#24, elapsed_time#25, origin_city_name#26, origin_state_abr#27)
res: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD = 
SchemaRDD[6] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:103
== Query Plan ==
== Physical Plan ==
CassandraTableScan [id#21,destination_city_name#22,destination_state_abr#23,distance#24,elapsed_time#25,origin_city_name#26,origin_state_abr#27], (CassandraRelation 10.234.31.231, 9042, 9160, roadtrips, roadtrip, org.apache.spark.sql.CassandraAwareSQLContext@54bebc7b, None, None, false, Some(Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml)), []

scala>
```

**Cassandra Table:**

```
 id | destination_city_name | destination_state_abr | distance | elapsed_time | origin_city_name | origin_state_abr
----+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+------------------
 23 |           Los Angeles |                    CA |     2475 |         1700 |         New York |               NY
 33 |           Los Angeles |                    CA |     2475 |         1444 |         New York |               NY
```

**Command retrieving only the column names and not records.**

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of records returned by the query is potentially large, the results aren't displayed by default.  If you'd like to see some of the retrieved records from the RDD, you could use the `first` or `take` methods:

```
val res = sqlContext.sql("select * from roadtrips.roadtrip")
res.first()
res.take(3)
```